# Type 'number' is not assignable to type '0 | 1'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to convert my project to Typescript, but I ran into the following error:
`Type 'number' is not assignable to type '0 | 1'`
The code looks as follows:

```
let pillarsCount = blockSides
    .map((blockSide) => {
      const sideVariations = blockSide.config || []
      if (sideVariations.length === 1) {
        return sideVariations.some((sv) => !!sv.hasPillar) ? 1 : 0
      }
      return 0
    })
    .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
```

Comment: What is `blockSides`?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surprised that TypeScript is inferring things that way, but you can fix it by explicitly typing the `reduce` operation:

```
let pillarsCount = blockSides
    .map((blockSide) => {
      const sideVariations = blockSide.config || []
      if (sideVariations.length === 1) {
        return sideVariations.some((sv) => !!sv.hasPillar) ? 1 : 0
      }
      return 0
    })
    .reduce<number>((a, b) => a + b, 0)
// −−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBARgGxMA1gZQJYBMCmEYC8MA2gFAwUwDe5ldoYAZhgOYBcJVAFgIYQAKGBAh4AnDlFEBXHAF8ANNV4ChI8TEY8EEOQF1aFWaX0IcsAA6qxEAMIgpYWEUTJ02PAZgA6ALY9zABQBLqiYuACUhAB81J4UDNAwEO4AamIYPFAY4PjOSKHuXgzMLDAAPmUk%20nQUGIwwAcm4aaIZWTlepmAsUFyEBEQAjJE0NZSiZlKiYEmp6ZnZkF4QID44QRAAbpEEMQCEe1teyoLCYpEA-DCDMBwADHEwRmMTUFMzD3Sy4Z5eE1hSYA4AA8YCkPjgOFEUSCPEUcB2MR4MAA1PBFHdwkA)

---

Side note: Since you're explicitly checking that `sideVariations` has `length === 1` before doing the `some` call, there's no need for the `some` call, just use the single object you know is there:

```
let pillarsCount = blockSides
    .map((blockSide) => {
      const sideVariations = blockSide.config || []
      if (sideVariations.length === 1) {
        return sideVariations[0].hasPillar ? 1 : 0
// −−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      }
      return 0
    })
    .reduce<number>((a, b) => a + b, 0)
// −−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBARgGxMA1gZQJYBMCmEYC8MA2gFAwUwDe5ldoYAZhgOYBcJVAFgIYQAKGBAh4AnDlFEBXHAF8ANNV4ChI8TEY8EEOQF1aFWaX0IcsAA6qxEAMIgpYWEUTJ02PAZgA6ALY9zABQBLqiYuACUhAB81J704NAwEO4AamIYPFAYCYTwSKHuXgzMLDAAPmUk+nR0GIwwAcm4aaIZWQlepmAsUFyEBEQAjJE0NZSiZlKiYEmp6ZnZkMQADLpeyoLCYjAA-DCDMBzLpAD0JzCASERX1zdXAHoPj0-PL6+vcZRGYxQTUFMzxzosnCni8EywUmAOAAPGApD44DhRFEgjxFHBIgQYjwYABqeCKZYgs6XW73d5AA)

Comment: Works like a charm, Thank you. You're right about the side note, thanks for pointing that out!